# Какая запятая нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, и

Я буду рад если оппозиция победит, и Украина войдет в Евросоюз.
Я буду рад, если оппозиция победит и Украина войдет в Евросоюз.

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Comment: Я понимаю, что вопрос не своевременной, но подскажите, что за учебник и какого года? Очень уж занимательные предложения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Верен второй вариант: *Я буду рад, если оппозиция победит и Украина войдет в Евросоюз* — сложноподчинённое предложение с однородными придаточными, соединёнными одиночным союзом.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

**Я буду рад, если оппозиция победит и Украина войдет в Евросоюз.**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором главное предложение (*Я буду рад*) является общим для двух однородных придаточных, соединенных одиночным союзом "и" (*если оппозиция победит **и*** [если] *Украина войдет в Евросоюз*).
Запятая в этом случае нужна только перед союзом "если".

[Трудные случаи пунктуации. Запятая перед союзом «И»](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)

*Я буду рад, **если** эта книга покажется вам интересной **и** мои советы пригодятся вам для решения задач и проблем* (Р. Фад).